# How to parse a widget that returns javascript to build DOM instead of HTML?

Tags: javascript, bash, widget

We are provided a widget that prints a playlist of songs provided by NPR. We need to fetch, programmatically every few seconds, the currently airing song, the one at the top of the list, and then save it to a file or something. Easy right? `wget http://composer.nprstations.org/asasfasdfasf | sed 'find/it' > nowplaying.txt` or something to that effect. Could be python, bash, pascal, whatever.

HOWEVER.. upon further inspection, the widget does not simply return the HTML, it returns a bunch of javascript that then builds the DOM. So it's client side logic that builds the playlist, not server side, or maybe both. Once the page is loaded, I can just as easily get the text we need, typing something like `$('.now-playing a').html()[0]` in the console would do the trick, but I don't know how we could do this programmatically.

So we need a browser with a javascript engine to first process the page before we can parse it. What would you recommend we do??

Thanks for any help!!

this is the entire response from the widget server:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/widgets/src/whatson.js"></script>
  <script src="/widgets/src/jquery-deparam.js"></script>
  <script>
    var configuration = {
      schedule: 'now'
    };
    if ( window.location.search ) configuration = $.extend({}, configuration, $.deparam( (window.location.search).replace('?','') ));
    $(function(){ 
      $('.now-playing').whatsOn( configuration ); 
    }); 
   </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="now-playing"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i would use a browser, they works great. grasemonkey and tampermonkey let you automate it. i'm sure somebody can reinvent the wheel and make an invisible browser, but nothing as easy and common as userscripts. oh, and please don't hammer-ping NPR, the programs last a lot longer than a few seconds...

Comment: you should 1st check what does the `whatson.js`.

Comment: @dandavis do you know if a userscript could then save the text to a file? oh, and we're not literally going to make a request every second. I'm in touch with NPR Digital Services so I'll see what they recommend

Comment: ch/ff can save it to a text file, but not a specific text file, so you would be better off sending the data/event to your webserver using POST upon discovery. or, mod your browser using about:config or cmd-line flags

Comment: @jm666 whatson.js connects to the api and uses our station id (a url parameter) to get the data. I've poked around the object in the js consol, but couldn't find any way to output json or an array or anything.

Comment: @jm666 you were right! With the widget open in chrome and by analyzing network requests in chrome's dev console, I found the API url that I needed. jm666 if you make this an answer I will give you credit. Thanks!

Comment: @DanMantyla im happy than you found the solution. Good work. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, from what you posted, the page runs the `whatsOn JS` function.

As you told, in commnets it connects to the API with the your `station ID`.

So, the next step is simulating the same - you can try connect with the `wget`, or some scripting language, to the same API with the same "station ID" as JS does, and analyse what you got.

And repeat the same with the next step, if needed.

It is impossible to solve the problem without access...

Alternatively, you can check the [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) perl module. Here are some [examples](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.75/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox/Examples.pm) and an [cookbook](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox/Cookbook.pod) ;)